# How to make all page tabs visible in mobile view blogger

Tags: html, css, web, mobile, blogger

I have created a site with the Blogger platform.
I have 4 pages on my blog, everything in the page list looks great on PC (this is my blog: https://www.onlinebouwdroger.be/p/home.html).
I want my mobile version to be just like the desktop version (so no Custom mobile template).

Here's the problem I'm encoutering (see screenshots below):

- The pages bar shows only the first two pages on Mobile, and then puts
  others in 'More...'
- When clicking on 'More...' the page titles are
  all messed up.

I would prefer to just have all 4 pages shown in the page list on mobile, just like on desktop.
I get that a mobile screen isn't wide enough to put the 4 titles in one row (like on desktop), but is there a way to put the last 2 page titles below the first 2 (so the titles are displayed 2x2)?

Or if not possible, the drop-down menu should at least look and work decently.
Like I mentioned, I want to show Desktop theme on mobile devices, not Mobile theme.

[desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YbCG.jpg)

[mobile view without clicking on 'more'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlYqQ.jpg)

[mobile view after clicking on 'more'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sye0P.jpg)

How do I solve this issue so that the full page list is displayed on Mobile as well? (Without having to switch to Mobile template?) Or how do I make the drop-down menu look/function properly?

I've looked everywhere online, but can't seem to find a proper answer.

Thanks in advance!

Juliette

Comment: Nice question! In the future please post the relative code in your question. Also, please consider doing it for this one as well. It makes it more likely to be answered.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I'm quite new to html, so not sure which part of my code I should post..

Answer (score 0):

You can target smaller screens in your css like this:

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 400px) { 
         myNavbar { css in here }
    }
```

From there you can change how the links are displayed.

Comment: Thank you! I've indeed succesfully used this before, for displaying a different background image on mobile. But I'm very new to html and don't know what to put in between the brackets to change how the links are displayed..
Also, where do I put this is my html code? Like I said, I'm very new to this and only know the basics.. Thanks!

Comment: This would be part of the CSS and the rest of your style markup. (style tag) Also, considering you have roughly 2k lines of CSS, I'd suggest moving that into a separate file. Cleaner looking code and it can be cached to help load all your pages better.  I'm not sure what tool you're using to build this page, but so much of the html is unnecessary  (as is with most page builders) and complicates a solution. But I am attempting to dig through it to see what you can add to fix your issue rather than just tell you start over with bootstrap and be done in 5min.

Comment: Thanks Phaelax! I'm using Blogger for this site (can't change the platform since it's for a client) and I mainly did the design aspect.
I can't seem to find any fix for my issue online, so keep me posted if you find something. That woud be amazing!

Comment: Hi Phaelax, sorry to bother you again, but I'm kinda desperate! I can't find anything about this online.. Do you have any idea of how I could fix this? Thank you so much!

Comment: I looked at it further and frankly, the blogger code is such a mess with 99% of it unnecessary.  Remove the classes from the nav (pagelist, overflowable, etc..) and just design your own navbar css.  It'll be a lot simpler than trying to override all the garbage that's being done.

Comment: Hm okay thanks for replying! Only problem is that I'm not a web developer (I'm a designer), nor do I know any html/css so I guess I won't be able to fix this..

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the CSS for the Tab inside media query to hide/show Tabs based on screen size

/* Extra small devices (phones, 420px and down) */

`@media only screen and (max-width: 420px) {...}`

/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) *\

`@media only screen and (min-width: 420px) and (max-width: 768px) {...}`

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 769px and up) */

`@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {...}`

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */

`@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {...}`

/* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */

`@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {...}`

Comment: Hi, thanks! I've used this before, for displaying a different background image on mobile. But what I'm looking fot is the css that I need to put between the {...} brackets. I'm very new to html, so not sure what I need to put there...
Also, where exactly do I put this in my html code? I put the background image option behind "<style> body {", do I put this there as well?

Comment: Hi Chinmay, sorry to bother you again, but I'm kinda desperate! I can't find anything about this online.. Do you have any idea of what I have to put between the brackets {...} to fix it? Thank you so much!

Comment: You have to device-specific css rule which you want to target

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp